# Load a css style when over on a different style

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a index.php, with a menu, I want to see the class menuitem:hover active when I'm over the item with the class (link), but I also want to see the class menuitem:hover active when I'm hover other li of the link menu. Ok, I will explain that With the real example:

I have a dropdown menu. When you're over the top link it generates a border from the bottom of the top link, but when you're on the dropdown menu of this top link the border disappears because you're hover the dropdown not over the link. I want to see the border when you're on the dropdown and when you're over the link.

Here is the code. But NOTE you can see better in action (I know is a bit difficult to understand the problem).

index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/css/layout.css" media="all">
    </head>

    <body>

    <div id="headerbar">
        Hello World
    </div>

    <div id="mainmenu-bar">
        <div id="mainmenu-content">
            <img src="./lib/images/logo.png" height="75" width="75" style="float:left;margin-top:5px;">
            <h1 style="color:white; float:left; margin-bottom:0px; display:inline-block;">Title</h1>

            <div id="mainmenu">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Inicio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="menuitem" href="#">Acerca de</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="#">Producto</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Nosotros</a></li>
                            </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a class="menuitem" href="#">Servicios</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Servicio uno</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Servicio dos</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Servicio tres</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Servicio cuatro</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <h1 color="white">Hello World</h1>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

layout.css

```
@font-face{font-family: Maven Pro; src: url(../fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf);}

body{font-family:Maven Pro; background:#ECECEC; border:0; font-size:100%; vertical-align:baseline; margin:0; padding:0;}

#headerbar{height:30px; float:right; margin-right:20px; margin-top:5px;}

/*MAIN MENU BAR*/
#mainmenu-bar{background:#4C84BC; width:100%; height:90px; overflow: hidden;}
#mainmenu-content{margin: 0 auto; width:1000px;}
#mainmenu{margin-top:35px; display:inline-block;}
#mainmenu ul li{float: left; margin-right: 20px; list-style: none;}
#mainmenu ul li a {color:#FFF; text-decoration: none;}
#mainmenu ul li a:hover {color: #474747;}
#mainmenu ul ul {display: none; padding: 0px; position: absolute; width: auto; margin-left: 0px;}
#mainmenu ul li:hover>ul {background: #fff; width:220px; border-right:1px solid #a4a4a4; margin-top:21px; z-index:9; position: absolute; box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); -moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); -o-box-shadow: 0 2px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); border-top:3px solid #FCD100; display: block;}
#mainmenu ul ul li {float: none;position: relative; text-decoration: none; display: block;}
#mainmenu ul ul li a{text-decoration: none;}
.menuitem {padding:11px 15px 17px;}
.menuitem:hover{border-bottom:6px solid #FCD100;}
```

I know that do this maybe onli will be possible with JQuery but if is with CSS3 better.

Comment: Can you provide a link or jsfiddle or something of the sort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the following rule:

```
.menuitem li:hover{border-bottom:6px solid #FCD100;}
```

or even this to make both obey the same rule:

```
.menuitem:hover,
.menuitem li:hover
{
    border-bottom:6px solid #FCD100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in order  to see the border when you're on the dropdown and when you're over the link.
add the same class ".both-element" for both elements.

```
.both-element:hover{border-bottom:6px solid #FCD100;}
```